# How to read a json obj created with the nlohmann::json lib

Tags: c++, json, windows, nlohmann-json

I'm getting a `JSON` string from a curl request, like this:

```
    [
      {
        "name": "P309",
        "path": "P309",
        "sha": "b9dbfa7ceb9db3b73c84ff326a418bdd50c1b227",
        "type": "file",
        "_links": {
          "self": "https://api.github.com/repos//files/contents/P309?ref=main",
          "git": "https://api.github.com/repos//files/git/blobs/b9dbfdd50c1b227",
          "html": "https://github.com//files/blob/main/P309"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "P310",
        "path": "P310",
        "sha": "b9dbfa7ceb9db3b73c84ff326a418bdd50c1b227",
        "_links": {
          "self": "https://api.github.com/repos//files/contents/P309?ref=main",
          "git": "https://api.github.com/repos//files/git/blobs/b9dbfdd50c1b227",
          "html": "https://github.com//files/blob/main/P309"
        }
      },
    ]
```

How can I parse/read it using the [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) lib?

I've found this example:

```cpp
/*
  "emulators": [
    {
      "general_info": {
        "dev_id": "0123456789"
      }
    }
  ]
*/
    for(json& o : data["emulators"]) {
        json& gi = o["general_info"];
        std::cout << gi["dev_id"] << '\n';
    }
```

My `JSON` being parsed doesn't have any 'title/header', I'm confused about how to read it.

I tried:

```cpp
  using json = nlohmann::json;
  json data = json::parse(downloaded_data);
  
  for(json& o : data[0]) {
     auto git = o["git"].get<std::string>();
     auto name = o["name"].get<std::string>();
  }
```

`git` outputs the value correctly, however, when reading `name` it throws an exception.

This is the value of [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p1Bz.png) in the debugger
and this, of [o](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmone.png).

Can I get any help on this?

Comment: I think your json is invalid, there is missing comma after `"sha": "b9dbfa7ceb9db3b73c84ff326a418bdd50c1b227"`.

Comment: @pptaszni i cut some parts of the json to not spam the question, i have fixed it, sorry.

Comment: i guess, it should be something like this: `for (json& o : data) { auto git = o["_links"]["git"].get<std::string>(); auto name = o["name"].get<std::string>(); }`